# getting an error 'TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import random 
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#global var for the games
FPS = 32
SCREENWIDTH = 289
SCREENHEIGHT = 511
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
GROUNDY = SCREENHEIGHT * 0.8
GAME_SPRITE = {}
GAME_SOUND = {}
PLAYER = 'imgs/bird.png'
BACKGROUND = 'imgs/background.png'
PIPE = 'imgs/pipe.png'


def welcomeScreen():
   
    playerx = int(SCREENWIDTH/5)
    playery = int((SCREENHEIGHT - GAME_SPRITE['player'].get_height())/2)
    messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITE['message'].get_width())/2)
    messagey = int(SCREENHEIGHT*0.13)
    basex = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # if user clicks on cross button, close the game
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # If the user presses space or up key, start the game for them
            elif event.type==KEYDOWN and (event.key==K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
                return
            else:
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITE['background'], (0, 0))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITE['player'], (playerx, playery))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITE['message'], (messagex,messagey ))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITE['base'], (basex, GROUNDY))    
                pygame.display.update()
                FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird')
    GAME_SPRITE['numbers'] = (
        pygame.image.load('imgs/1.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/2.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/3.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/4.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/5.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/6.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/7.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/8.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/9.png').convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load('imgs/0.png').convert_alpha()
    )

    GAME_SPRITE['pipe'] =( 
    pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.image.load(PIPE).convert_alpha(),180),
    pygame.image.load(PIPE).convert_alpha()

    )
    GAME_SPRITE['message'] = pygame.image.load('imgs/message.png').convert_alpha()
    GAME_SPRITE['base'] = pygame.image.load('imgs/base.png').convert_alpha()



    GAME_SOUND['crash'] = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/crash.mp3')
    GAME_SOUND['hit'] = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/hit.mp3')
    GAME_SOUND['swoosh'] = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/swoosh.mp3')


    GAME_SPRITE['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert
    GAME_SPRITE['player'] = pygame.image.load(PLAYER).convert_alpha()


    while True:
        welcomeScreen()
```

line 40, in welcomeScreen
SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITE['background'], (0, 0))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method
i tried doing multiple things also searched online, however didn't get the answer. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Your assignment to `GAME_SPRITE['background']` appears to be cut short, compared to all the similar images.

Comment: It is a typo. `pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert` needs to be `pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```py
GAME_SPRITE['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert
```

With this assignment, your `background` is a [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert). You need to call it, like this:

```py
GAME_SPRITE['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `convert` part of `GAME_SPRITE['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert` a function or method? If so you are missing the `()` after it.

Change that line to

> ```py
> GAME_SPRITE['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert()
> ```

and see if it does what you expect.

If that fixes your problem then the issue was that you have assigned the `convert` *function* to `GAME_SPRITE['background']`, rather than calling `convert()` and assigning the returned value.